# Error when passing an enum for code in NSError initializer

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying setup some custom error codes for my app using enum. But I get an error when I called the NSError initializer. Below is the code I have so far,

```
enum FYIError : Int{
    case emptyData = 1
    case apiError = 2
}

class Test{
    func customErrorTest (){
       let customError:NSError = NSError(domain: "mydomain", code: FYIError.apiError, userInfo: Test.userInfo(""))
    }

    static private func userInfo (message:String) -> [NSObject: AnyObject]{

    var msg:String = message
    if (msg.characters.count<0){
        msg = "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later."
    }

    var dict = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
    dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]        = msg
    dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = msg
    dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey]             = msg

    return dict
}
}
```

The error I get is as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the compiler error suggests you are trying to pass in an `FYIError` type as opposed to an `Int`. To get the raw value that you assigned to that enum case simply use the `rawValue` property as so:

```
let customError:NSError = NSError(domain: "mydomain", code: FYIError.apiError.rawValue, userInfo: Test.userInfo(""))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this because you need to use the rawValue of the enum:

```
let customError:NSError = NSError(domain: "mydomain", code: FYIError.apiError.rawValue, userInfo: Test.userInfo(""))
```

code needs type Int,  using the specified enum will only get you a member of the enum type,  the rawValue will get you the Int value if your specified enum